# Can I use something like copy as doc link or copy as view link in Xpages (in the client)

Tags: xpages

Can I use something like copy as doc link or copy as view link in Xpages (in the client)? Would like something built-in, but maybe you have to build a custom control?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's not anything built in, as far as I know. Linking to the document and view will only work if the design element is set to launch a specific XPage instead.

You can get a handle on the relevant URL components via the XSPUrl class, accessed via context.getUrl()

Comment: I think this really kind of hurts the usability of Xpages in the client vis-a-via the old client. Copy as link was really really a great solution. I wonder if you could right a cc that would copy a url to the clipboard that would work the same way? Plunk it in your docs. If feasible I might try to write it.

Comment: Bear in mind copy as doc link works because of one of the key limitations of Notes Client that XPages overcomes, only having one Document datasource on a page or at least in focus. For a single implementation, it should be easy. Not sure about copying to clipboard, maybe a "permalink" idea is more fitting for web. For a more flexible solution, it's worth considering how to handle multiple datasources on a page, different operating systems (inc. mobile), possible differing hosts internally/externally. By all means try it though. Doesn't need to be all at once (look at my XPages OpenLog work)

Comment: The URL of the current page is up in the browser, so it can be shared easily. However you need to take extra care that it is precise when you do partial refreshes to load different data